# Forcing a URL field to not have "http://www." using regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation

I need to validate a URL field for an input field that deals with a finicky API that will accept URL strings in a very certain format - no www's and no http's attached to the start of the string, or it breaks. A javascript handler grabs the data from the validation.php file. I have everything working except for one field.

---

So, for example I want

> example.com/example

and

> example.com

to pass validation, but I want

> http://example.com/example

and

> http://www.example.com/example

and any variation including any derivation of http:// or www. to not validate.

---

The regex I have below currently allows any type of URL including http and www. I want it to ONLY allow the above type of URL string, but not sure how to go about this.

```
    // API URL VALIDATION
    if ($formfield == "api_url") {
        if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $value)) {
            echo "Please enter your URL without the http://www part attached" 
        } else {
            echo "<span>Valid</span>";
        }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: so remove the first part of the reg exp or Remove the part you do not want in code. Just chop off the part you do not want and reset the value of the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple negative lookahead based regex in `preg_match`:

```
~^(?!https?://)(?!www\.).+$~i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bF1bO9/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "not match" a subject that begins with http or www:

```
if(!preg_match('/^((http|ftp)s?:\/\/)?(www\.).+?/', $value))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `.htaccess` `mod rewrite` rule. But in your case it looks like you need to validate a input field so it doesn't apply to all cases. Here is function which will allow/dis-allow such protocols in the url.

```
function remove_protocol($url) {
   $filter_protocol = array('http://', 'https://', 'http://www');
   foreach($filter_protocol as $d) {
      if(strpos($url, $d) === 0) {
         return str_replace($d, '', $url);
      }
   }
   return $url;
}
```

in the `$filter_protocol` array you can keep on defining protocols not to allow in urls for instance `ftp://`